# Use SetEnv Variable in htaccess Rewrite Rule

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In our `httpd.conf` virtual host block we have

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "v2_us_es"
```

Is it possible to use that variable in a `.htaccess` file

Something like

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /media/sitemaps/%{MAGE_RUN_CODE}/sitemap.xml [L]
```

Is this possible?

I viewed the following links, but none of them do what I am trying to do

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727720/conditional-setenv-in-htaccess
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008123/how-to-use-getenv-in-php-and-setenv-in-a-htaccess-with-a-compiled-php-cgi-on
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638637/how-to-use-the-setenv-variable-in-apache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax to use environment variables in mod_rewrite is `%{ENV:VARNAME}`:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ media/sitemaps/%{ENV:MAGE_RUN_CODE}/sitemap.xml [L]
```

Comment: This still wouldn't have worked if the OP was setting the environment variable using `SetEnv` (as stated in the question) - even when setting this in the vHost. `SetEnv` (mod_env) simply executes too late for mod_rewrite to pick it up. In addition to using the correct syntax (as stated here), they would have needed to use `SetEnvIf` (mod_setenvif) (as stated in the other answer), which runs earlier.

Answer (score 2):

`SetEnv` variables just return empty strings in a `RewriteRule`. I think this is because they haven't been set when the `RewriteRule` is executed. But `SetEnvIf` will work, so you could try:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^.*$ MAGE_RUN_CODE=v2_us_es
```

and then use it with:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /media/sitemaps/%{ENV:MAGE_RUN_CODE}/sitemap.xml [L]
```

The `Request_URI ^.*$` bit in the `SetEnvIf` just checks that the requested page is something or nothing, so always sets the variable.

It would probably be better configured as a `RewriteMap` in the Apache config file.